# Make background span across multiple GridLayout children

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I am trying to implement GridLayout where some of the children have shared background image.

If I have something like this:

[image]

For children 1,2,3,5 and two children below 2 and 3, I would like to set the same background image. So, the background images would stretch like this:

[image]

How to accomplish that and is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Make the `GridLayout` have a transparent background and layer it on top of two `ImageViews`. Layering is accomplished in xml by using `RelativeLayouts` (usually) and ordering the items in a specific way in the xml. Objects declared later inside the xml are put on top of ones declared earlier.